# audio signal processing in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, signals, filtering, processing

I have a question regarding signal processing of audio file in matlab.

what I want to do is the following:

- I will record respiratory efforts and save it in wav file.
- Read the wav file in matlab, and only take the frequency between [200-800] Hz.
- Plot the signal for this band [200-800]Hz

can anyone tell me how can I code those steps in matlab.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Matlab has good support for audio (better than Linux/Mac at least). Look at `audiorecorder`, `audiowrite`, `wavread`, `filter` (in conjunction with `firls` or any other filter design function that can do bandpass filtering), and `plot`.